# Showing different text on dropdown selection vs dropdown options

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I have a requirement where my drop-down values in my select are an expanded div which has 3 lines.  For example my options Could be something like below

```
Honda Accord
19'
Blue
--------------
Honda Civic
17'
Red
```

This is what my dropdown would look like when expanded.  So instead of regular one line option I have a div with more detailed options.  The challenge I am facing is when making my selection (I can correctly display the grid as above) my dropdown selection value shows as the context of the whole div.  So for example my dropdown after selection would look like this.

`[Honda Civic17'Red]`

I am using Angular Material for my dropdown.  Is anyone aware of a way to set the selection to another value than the option text?  For example I would like my dropdown when selected to display `[Honda Civic]` instead of `[Honda Covic17'Red]`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the display of the selected item using `MatSelectTrigger`. An example is provided here: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label.

Comment: Perfect! thank you.  That is exactly what I was looking for.